# How to recover after ReWrite failure?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I want to open a typed file as random access. This is done by setting the `FileMode` in `fmOpenReadWrite`. This requires the file to exist and I test whether the file exists and if not, `ReWrite` it and close it. See code below.

```
  var fl: file of _some_record_type_;
      fn: string;

  AssignFile (fl, fn);
  if not FileExists (fn) then
  begin
     ReWrite (fl);
     CloseFile (fl); // Now an empty file exists
  end; // if

  FileMode := fmOpenReadWrite;
  Reset (FTrack_File);
  // ...further rad and write operations...
```

This works great except when `fn` is an illegal file name, for example when specifying a non-existing drive. It raises an exception at `ReWrite`. I cannot recover from the error by surrounding the `ReWrite` by `try..except` because any reference to that file or *any other file* raises an access violation exception. It appears that some condition has been set that prevents any file i/o.

Somebody knows how to handle this situation?

Comment: Try..except should allow you to recover from the error. You should be able to perform i/o on file F1, (after assigning a valid file name and successfully calling reset or rewrite), and it certainly should have no effect on any other file i/o.  Perhaps the access violation is being caused by some other problem.  Can you show us some code with try..except that leads to an access violation?

Comment: After the AssignFile the files remains assigned until a CloseFile. But I cannot close the file when I assigned an illegal file name, neither can it be Reset or rewritten. I tried the write a .ini file and that crashed as well at ReWrite in another procedure with another file variable and another file name.

Comment: You only need to call CloseFile if you've successfully opened the file with Reset or Rewrite.  You can call AssignFile as many times as you like without calling CloseFile.  Once the Rewrite has failed with the illegal file name, just call AssignFile again with a legal file name

Comment: +1 for telling me this. I'll try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can switch to using exceptions (with `{$I+}`), and then use `try..except`. (It's usually the default, unless you've unchecked `I/O Checking` in the Project Options dialog (`Project->Options->Delphi Compiler->Compiling->Runtime Errors->I/O checking` from the main menu).

If that box is unchecked, it sets the option `{$I-}`, which uses [`IOResult`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.IOResult).

If you want to keep using `IOResult`, you'll need to check it after using the file functions. Checking it automatically resets the InOutRes variable to `0`, clearing the previous error value.

```
AssignFile (fl, fn);
if not FileExists (fn) then
begin
  ReWrite (fl);
  if IOResult <> 0 then
    // You've had an error.
  CloseFile (fl); // Now an empty file exists
end; // if
```

`IOResult` can be found in the `System` unit.

You really should be moving away from the old style IO routines, BTW. They're ancient, and don't properly work with Unicode data. You can accomplish the same thing using a `TFileStream`, which would give you proper exception handling and support for Unicode. Here's a quick console app sample (tested with XP3 on Win 7):

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, Classes, Windows;

type
  TMyRec = record
    anInt: Integer;
    aBool: Boolean;
    aByte: Byte;
  end;

var
  FS: TFileStream;
  MyRec: TMyRec;
const
  TheFile = 'C:\TempFiles\test.dat';

begin
  MyRec.anInt := 12345;
  MyRec.aBool := True;
  MyRec.aByte := 128;
  FS := TFileStream.Create(TheFile, fmCreate or fmOpenReadWrite);
  try
    FS.Write(MyRec, SizeOf(TMyRec));
    // Clear the content and confirm it's been cleared
    FillChar(MyRec, SizeOf(TMyRec), 0);
    WriteLn('anInt: ', MyRec.anInt, ' aBool: ', MyRec.aBool, ' aByte: ', MyRec.aByte);

    FS.Position := 0;
    FS.Read(MyRec, SizeOf(TMyRec));
  finally
    FS.Free;
  end;
  // Confirm it's read back in properly
  WriteLn('anInt: ', MyRec.anInt, ' aBool: ', MyRec.aBool, ' aByte: ', MyRec.aByte);
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Comment: +1 and thanks for the explanation of streams. When I read your example I realized that this is a nice situation to try out streams, with typed files it should be easy. I usually use text files and I have still not seen a good explanation how to handle text files in a proper way. In almost all situations I use line oriented files reading and writing lines of text. I've not seen a good working example. As for unicode: I've succeeded to avoid it.